# how to convert my integer value to a string of binary values

Tags: r, binary, integer

I need to convert a nummeric value (integer) to a binary string in R. This is what my dataframe looks like:

```
     V1 V2 V3
  1  1  90 336
  2  1  90 336
  3  3  4  420
  4  12 2  413 
  5  12 4  411
```

I want a first row with a zero followed by 90 1's and 336 zeros again (so read by row). So the output would be a matrix with 427 columns and 5 rows. Also if possible I would like the NA's to be read as for 1's.

Dirk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text="     V1 V2 V3
  1  1  90 336
  2  1  90 336
  3  3  4  420
  4  12 2  413 
  5  12 4  411")
mat <- matrix(apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  rep(c(0, 1, 0), x)
}), nrow = 5, ncol = 427, byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: Ok and if i would want to use it for my entire data: which has also three columns but 101 rows. it's a bit much to do manually

Comment: `matrix(apply(df, 1, function(x) { rep(c(0, 1, 0), x) }), nrow = nrow(df), byrow = TRUE)` would be more general.

Comment: apparently it doesn't take because there are NA's in my data, can i fix this?

Comment: for now i will just omit the NA's.

Comment: Each row has max 1 NA? Then you could just replace it with the right number of 0 or 1.